# Animate SVGs like its being drawn using jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg

I have created small snippet based on [Linea](http://linea.io/) SVG iconsets. I want to make the svg icon to animate on its stroke path like [Vivus SVG](https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/).

How can we do it using object as `<object>` is pretty much the best option to use if you want to be able to manipulate an SVG without having to put it inline in your HTML.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="basic_compass.svg"></object>
```

Here is my HTML

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif:400,700,400italic);

.container {
    max-width: 1200px !important;
    margin: 100px 0;
}

.container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}

.col_third { 
    width: 32%;
 position: relative;
 display:inline;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
    text-align:center;
 margin-right: 2%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.end { margin-right: 0 !important; }

h5 {font-size:18px; font-weight: normal; font-family: "Montserrat";}
p{font-size: 14px; line-height:24px;font-family: "Noto Serif";}

.svg-icon-holder {
 height: 64px;
 overflow: hidden;
 min-width: 1px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col_third">
    <div class="svg-icon-holder" data-animation-delay="400" data-animation="true" data-animation-speed="65" data-size="80"><object type="image/svg+xml" data="http://linea.io/_assets/_svgs/_basic/basic_paperplane.svg"></object></div>
    <h5>Service Style</h5>
    <p><span style="color: #666;">Ut elit tellus, luctus nec magna mattis et, pulvinar dapibus lorem leo ultricies et vitae enim.</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col_third">
    <div class="svg-icon-holder" data-animation-delay="200" data-animation="true" data-animation-speed="150" data-size="80"><object type="image/svg+xml" data="http://linea.io/_assets/_svgs/_basic/basic_compass.svg"></object></div>
    <h5>Service Style</h5>
    <p><span style="color: #666;">Ut elit tellus, luctus nec magna mattis et, pulvinar dapibus lorem leo ultricies et vitae enim.</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col_third end">
    <div class="svg-icon-holder" data-animation-delay="300" data-animation="true" data-animation-speed="200" data-size="80"><object type="image/svg+xml" data="http://linea.io/_assets/_svgs/_software/software_transform_bezier.svg" ></object></div>
    <h5>Service Style</h5>
    <p><span style="color: #666;">Ut elit tellus, luctus nec magna mattis et, pulvinar dapibus lorem leo ultricies et vitae enim.</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be simplest if you put the animation and javascript inside the SVG file. I suspect the tool won't do cross-document animation.

Comment: @RobertLongson Would you suggest any plugin which do the job without more effort as there are 500+ icons which i want to animate.

Comment: plugin suggestions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: How can i put the animation and javascript inside the SVG file? I don't know how to write animation code.

Comment: I guess you'd have to read up on one of the ways to do that, i.e. CSS animation, SMIL or javascript animation.